# Css3 responsive slider automate

Tags: html, css

I have set up a slider with using CSS3 only as described [here.](http://csscience.com/responsiveslidercss3/)

My question is, I have seen css3 animations that are automatic, is there any way to get this slider to auto rotate and still have the buttons work?

The css looks like this:

```
/* Slider Setup */

input {
display: none;
}

#slide1:checked ~ #slides .inner { margin-left:0; }
#slide2:checked ~ #slides .inner { margin-left:-100%; }
#slide3:checked ~ #slides .inner { margin-left:-200%; }
#slide4:checked ~ #slides .inner { margin-left:-300%; }


#overflow {
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

#slides .inner {
width: 500%;
line-height: 0;
}

#slides article {
width: 20%;
float: left;
}

/* Slider Styling */

/* Control Setup */

#controls {
margin: -25% 0 0 0;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
}

#controls label { 
display: none;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
opacity: 0.3;
}

#active {
margin: 23% 0 0;
text-align: center;
}

#active label {
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
display: inline-block;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
background: #bbb;
}

#active label:hover {
background: #ccc;
border-color: #777 !important;
}

#controls label:hover {
opacity: 0.8;
}

#slide1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2), 
#slide2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3), 
#slide3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(4), 
#slide4:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1){
background: url('imgs/next.png') no-repeat;
float: right;
margin: 0 -70px 0 0;
display: block;
}


#slide1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(4),
#slide2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1),
#slide3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2),
#slide4:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3){
background: url('imgs/prev.png') no-repeat;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 0 -70px;
display: block;
}

#slide1:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(1),
#slide2:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(2),
#slide3:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(3),
#slide4:checked ~ #active label:nth-child(4) {
background: #333;
border-color: #333 !important;
}

/* Info Box */

.info {
line-height: 20px;
margin: 0 0 -150%;
position: absolute;
font-style: italic;
padding: 30px 30px;
opacity: 0;
color: #000;
text-align: left;
}

.info h3 {
color: #333;
margin: 0 0 5px;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 22px;
font-style: normal;
}

/* Slider Styling */




/* Animation */

#slides .inner {
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
-moz-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
-ms-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
-o-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); /* easeInOutQuart */

-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
-moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
-ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
-o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); 
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); /* easeInOutQuart */
}

#slider {
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

#controls label{
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
}

#slide1:checked ~ #slides article:nth-child(1) .info,
#slide2:checked ~ #slides article:nth-child(2) .info,
#slide3:checked ~ #slides article:nth-child(3) .info,
#slide4:checked ~ #slides article:nth-child(4) .info{
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out 0.6s;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-out 0.6s;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-out 0.6s;
transition: all 1s ease-out 0.6s;
}

.info, #controls, #slides, #active, #active label, .info h3, .desktop, .tablet, .mobile {
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

And basically I have four of these, as my slides:

```
                <article >
                    <div class="info">                  
                        <div id="slideContent">
                            <div>
                                <h1></h1>
                                <h1 style="color:#ff9900;"><b></b></h1>
                            </div>
                            <div id="slideTxt"></div>
                            <div id="slideBtn"></div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    <img src="imgs/slide background" />
                </article>
```

Comment: I know automation is possible:http://www.anthonycalzadilla.com/css3-ATAT/ I just am confused on out to implement the concept.

Comment: You have to accept that CSS3 animations are well implemented only by some versions of most browsers. If you are ready to take on some javascript fallback, that's OK, but for your application you may also consider a smaller target. It's like if you develop an iPhone app and you know since beginning that it can't run on an Android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at the page source for that page. Since it is mostly in straight HTML that's the best place to start. Just right click on the page and hit "view source". All you need is right there.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but his page doesn't have any automation. The page I posted in the comments does, but not in a slideshow fashion. I am just not getting how to make the connection.

Comment: Oh so you want this to slide through on it's own? The simplest way for this is to use a pure JS timeout and on the timeout fire the click event for the radio buttons. In pure HTML and CSS; have a look at the source for the page you linked. It uses CSS3 animations.

Answer (score 0):

In looking around and trying something else, I have found that IE doesn't play well with the newer css3 animations. I therefore will look into doing this with javascript.

**Edit:So I decided to, since Jquery was the issue, just use some basic Javascript and make my own slider. I liked this css one and therefore just made a small JS to "fake click" the buttons for the slider every 10 seconds.**

```
    var labelNumber=1;
var flag = true;
function customSlideShow(){  
    if(flag){
        $("label[for='slide" + labelNumber + "']").trigger('click');
        labelNumber++;
        if (labelNumber==5){labelNumber=1;};
        setTimeout(customSlideShow, 10000);
    };}
```